# JavaScript counter increment on each click?

Tags: javascript, constants, javascript-objects

I need to correct this code in order to make it increment on each click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Click!</button>

<script>
    const counter = {
        cnt: 0,

        inc: function() {
            cnt++;
            console.log(cnt);
        }
    };

    const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution I have right now works fine, but not sure what are the concepts behind it, the solution is :

```
inc: function() {
    counter.cnt++;
    console.log(counter.cnt);
}
```

Comment: simply that `cnt++` is not incrementing the same `cnt` inside `counter`, you need to increment that by doing `counter.cnt`.

Comment: The concepts you are missing are basically concerned with scope: Which part of your code can see which variables.

Comment: So your code is working with `counter.cnt` because there is no global variable `cnt` only `counter` has it. Is there any other issues?

Comment: You need `counter.inc.bind(counter)`

Comment: @Alnitak the bind(counter) what does this do? I actually have not written anything like that but it still works fine

Comment: It is undefined at time of increment just put it inside function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its just a `scoping` issue,

```
 //Right approach would be,

 const counter = {
  cnt: 0,
  inc: function() {
   this.cnt++;
   console.log(this.cnt);
  }
 };
```

Your erroring code will look for a variable `cnt` declared in the current scope and traverse until the global one. It will throw error, if it doesn't find a reference.

Since you are passing the `inc` as an event listener, you have to bind the scope for it, otherwise, the `this` inside of that function will point to the element which triggers the event. Here in this case, the element would be a `button`.

```
button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc.bind(counter), false);
```

Or the most readable approach would be,

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() { 
 counter.inc() 
}, false);
```

Another reason for avoiding `.bind` is, once if you bind a context to a function using `.bind`. You cannot override the context of it after that. Even using `.call/.apply`

Comment: Does this really work? With the `addEventListener()` just pointing to the `inc()` function itself, the context for `this` should be lost.

Comment: @Sirko Yeah, That has to be dealt by the OP by using a `.bind`. Let me suggest that as well

Comment: @Sirko It's necessary, but insufficient

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.cnt` to access the `cnt` variable inside the function.

```
inc: function() {
            this.cnt++;
            console.log(this.cnt);
        }
```

Also you need to bind the value of `this` to `counter` inside the function like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc.bind(counter), false);
```

**Explaination:**

Here we are providing a `callback` function as the second argument to `addEventListener` function. For `this` inside this callback to be equal to the `counter` object we are using `bind`.

According to MDN Web Docs

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Therefore the value of `this` inside callback is set to `counter` and we can access its property `cnt` as `this.cnt`.

Comment: Are you using in the same way? What output you are getting please share it

Comment: when I click on it it gives NaN

Comment: @NaveenDINUSHKA please try with bind. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes It works with Bind @Rohit Agrawal .. What concepts do you think I  should work on in order to solve similar problems . Thank you for the help..Any links for any online resources are much appreciated!

Comment: @NaveenDINUSHKA I have updated my answer to explain it in detail. Please accept the answers which help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `button.addEventListener()` call you need to use 
either:

```
counter.inc.bind(counter)
```

or (since you appear to be using ES6)

```
() => counter.inc()
```

as the registered callback.

You also need to reference the correct `cnt` (i.e. `this.cnt`) within the `inc` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is:

```
inc: function() {
   cnt++;
   console.log(cnt);
}
```

cnt will refer to a global variable, not the property of counter as you want. You need to set it using `this.cnt++`.

The second things, is when you bind your addEventListener, it only passes the function, so `this` context when the function is called, is not actually the counter. You need to change it to:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      counter.inc();
}, false);

or button.addEventListener('click', () => counter.inc(), false);
```

or bind the counter.inc to counter like:

```
counter.inc = counter.inc.bind(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept is that you are in is object literal,  object literals encapsulate data, enclosing it in a tidy package, global This minimizes the use of global variables which can cause problems when combining code , in the first example you showed us you are retrieving global cnt variable and incrementing it which does'not exists in global scope, it is in counter scope, to retrieve it's properties and methods you need to call object first and then it's property like this object.(method or property)

```
inc: function() {
   counter.cnt++;//same as
   this.cnt++;//this
   console.log(counter.cnt);
}
```